# vba word: How to select images?

Tags: vba, ms-word

So for my particular application, I want to be able to select an image after I've copied it in from Excel, and then insert a caption.

I can successfully copy images using:

```
docapp.Selection.Range.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, Placement:=wdInLine
```

However, I'm having a lot of difficult just selecting the recently copied image so I can use

```
Selection.InsertCaption
```

What's the best way to select images?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I'm an idiot and have solved my own problem. It's not the prettiest code but it works:

The key is to use **document.InlineShapes.Select**:

```
Public Sub Chart2Word(chto As Chart, doc1 As Word.Document, docapp As Word.Application, _
                     Optional Title As Variant)
    Dim objpic As Word.InlineShape


    docapp.Activate
    chto.CopyPicture

    docapp.Selection.MoveEnd wdStory
    docapp.Selection.Move
    docapp.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter

    docapp.Selection.Range.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, Placement:=wdInLine

    doc1.InlineShapes(doc1.InlineShapes.Count).Select
    Label = Me.Range("LabelName").value
    If Not IsMissing(Title) Then

        docapp.Selection.InsertCaption Label:=Label, Title:=": " + Title
    End If
```

Comment: +2 for the attempt, -1 for reaching for help too soon =D